# Нужно от имени пользователя автоматический отправлять сообщения в определенный промежуток времени

Tags: python, api, telegram

**Вопрос:** Есть пользователь в Telegram. **Не бот!** Нужно от имени пользователя автоматический отправлять сообщения в определенный промежуток времени.

---

Какое API для этого использовать и возможно ли это вообще? **Telegram BOT API не подходит.**

---

Написал такого бота который в принципе выполняет то что я прошу, но оказывается мне нужно от имени пользователя а не от имени бота.

```
import time
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('|TOKEN|')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text == '/SOME TEXT/':
        while True:
            time.sleep(60)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '/SOME TEXT/')

bot.polling()
```

*Важно: я не прошу сделать за меня. Опишите пожалуйста что можно сделать, что прочитать дабы решить это.*

Comment: используйте библиотеку telethon. Вам необходимо сначала зарегистрировать ваше приложения на сайте telegram, затем авторизоваться в вашем приложении с помощью app_id, а потом уже можете делать что хотите

Comment: @danilshik у меня не приложение, просто скрипт. Который хочу запустить на сервере(хостинг) через ssh

Comment: по вашему мнению, скрипт не является приложением? Разве?

Comment: @danilshik понял спасибо. Не знал что это одно и тоже. Кодить начал недавно извините)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел ответ. Этот код выполняет то что я прошу

---

@danilshik подсказал что можно использовать библиотеку [Telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/)

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import time
# Use your own values from my.telegram.org
api_id = ВАШ ID
api_hash = 'ВАШ ХЭШ'

# The first parameter is the .session file name (absolute paths allowed)
with TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(client.send_message('me', 'Hello, myself!'))

async def main():
    while True:
        await client.send_message(ID группы, '/Любой текст/')
        await client.send_message(ID группы, '/Любой текст')
        time.sleep(60)


with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```